# Abaqus Milling Simulation

Tags: simulation, abaqus

I'm creating a simulation in abaqus of a endmill removing material from and aluminium plate. The simulation is almost working, but only the surface level element are being removed from the plate. The interior elements are not interacting with the end mill.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Phil

Comment: many guesses are possible -  from have you got your dimensions correct to have you set the advance between cuts? But it's all a guess - you need to show your code...